# Golang convert gob string to interface

Tags: go, decoding, gob

I am making a go program where I need to write a gob to a file. I used the .String() method to convert the gob to a string.

```
var network bytes.Buffer
encoder := gob.NewEncoder(&network)

_ = encoder.Encode(valueToEncode)

gobString := network.String()
```

then I will write the gob to a file, and later I will retrieve it and send it to this program:

```
var filebytes = []byte(file)  //i think that these two lines are the issue
network := bytes.NewBuffer(filebytes)

decoder := gob.NewDecoder(network)

var decoded interface{}

_ := decoder.Decode(&decoded)
```

but when i run this, it gives me this error:

> gob: encoded unsigned integer out of range

I think the issue is with the first two lines of the decoder program. So what should I put to properly decode the gob?

EDIT:
What I want is a .UnString() method for the gobString. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Decoding a gob-encoded `string` value into an `interface{}` gives another error: `local interface type *interface {} can only be decoded from remote interface type; received concrete type string`, so please provide a [mcve] that produces your error.

Comment: The code I gave throws the unsigned integer out of range error for me

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete and would give a compile-time error on its own. There are other parts which you didn't show. I tried to make it a minimal, running example and got the error I posted above. So please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your error so we can help with your actual error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) generates binary data from Go values. The result is not for textual representation, so you should not treat it as a `string`, but as a series of bytes, e.g. `[]byte`.

That said, do not use [`Buffer.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.String) but rather [`Buffer.Bytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Bytes) if you must obtain the encoded data.

Here's an example encoding and decoding a `string` value using `encoding/gob`:

```
// ENCODE
var network bytes.Buffer
encoder := gob.NewEncoder(&network)

valueToEncode := "Hello, 世界"
if err := encoder.Encode(valueToEncode); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

gobData := network.Bytes() // Save / serialize this byte slice

// DECODE
network2 := bytes.NewBuffer(gobData)
decoder := gob.NewDecoder(network2)

var decoded string
if err := decoder.Decode(&decoded); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.PrintTln(decoded)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TbnZkn9TD9f)):

```
Hello, 世界
```

Also note that if you intend to write the encoded data into a network connection or a file, you don't need `bytes.Buffer`, you can directly encode to those. If you must use `bytes.Buffer`, you may also use its [`Buffer.WriteTo()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteTo) method to write its contents into an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) (such as a file or network connection).